# JList list items squashed

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane, jlist

I've got my JList working, but only the first list item is its proper size. Everything else under it is squashed. I have searched all StackOverflow and haven't found much (getting it to work was all StackOverflow though)

```
package networks;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Matthew
 */
public class Networks extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static JPanel container = new JPanel();
    private static JPanel graphPanel = new JPanel();
    private static JPanel content = new JPanel();
    private static JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    private static Graphics2D g;
    private static JButton read = new JButton("Read");
    private static JButton breadth = new JButton("Breadth");
    private static JButton depth = new JButton("Depth");
    private String[] listModel = new String[10];
    private static JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane();
    private JList lists;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Networks networks = new Networks();
        networks.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Networks() {
        super("Station Networks");
        //Set up window and frames, buttons and lists
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        content.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(260,300));
        buttons.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttons, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        graphPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(255,255));

        //Add default value, tester
        listModel[0] = "The station list is currently empty";
        lists = new JList(listModel);
        lists.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        scroller.setViewportView(lists);
        BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(255,255,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g = im.createGraphics();

        //add listeners
        read.addActionListener(this);
        breadth.addActionListener(this);
        depth.addActionListener(this);

        //put it all togethe
        content.add(graphPanel);
        content.add(new Label("List"));
        content.add(scroller);
        buttons.add(read);
        buttons.add(breadth);
        buttons.add(depth);
        container.add(content);
        container.add(buttons);
        add(container);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
```

I have a function that later on adds list items. These items come in squashed. Is there a way to set size for the list items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an array for the data. Your array contains null values, except for the first entry. The null entries are being rendered funny.

Instead use the `DefaultListModel` and add items directly to it:

```
DefaultList model = new DefaultListModel();
model.addElement( "line1" );
JList list = new JList( model );
```